# Probability of drawing ball without replacement

Tags: combinatorics

There are $8$ red balls and $5$ blue balls. If they are drawn one after another without replacement, what is the probability of the $6$th ball to be red if the first $3$ are blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Given** that the first $3$ balls are blue, $2$ blue balls and $8$ red balls are left in random sequences, like

$\color{red}\bullet\color{blue}\bullet\color{red}{\bullet \bullet \bullet}\color{blue}{\bullet}\color{red}{\bullet\bullet\bullet\;\bullet}$

We needn't actually compute probabilities of various possible sequences.
Since "reds" don't have any preference for particular spots,
the probability that **any** of these $10$ spots is occupied by a red is $\frac8{10}$

You could countercheck, if you are an unbeliever, through computations of the sequences.

The probability will be $\Bbb P(BBR) + \Bbb P(BRR) + \Bbb P(RBR) + \Bbb P(RRR)$

$=\frac2{10} \frac19\frac88 + \frac2{10}\frac89\frac78 + ..... $